# What's the difference between "Be late", "Arrive late", and "Come late"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I'm not sure if saying "I was late", "I arrived late", and "I came late" are all correct and interchangeable. It would also help a lot if you could clarify if they sound idiomatic or formal.

Examples:

> I was late for work.
> I arrived late for work.
> I came late for work.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, David. We expect people to do some research before posting a question. In this case, you could look up the words **be**, **arrive**, **come** in a good dictionary, like this one: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come If your research does not answer your question, please edit your question to add details about your research, and to explain what specifically you are still unsure about, and maybe add explanations of when you might expect to use each sentence.

Comment: The short answer is that they are all correct. Also, your intuition is correct, in that "arrived" is more formal than "was." I wouldn't say that they are precisely the same in meaning, however. Perhaps you can do a bit more study along those lines and ask more specific questions as they come up.

Comment: Don't forget: I got to work late. got to x is very common in English for the verb arrive.